# Pagination for Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to extract multiple pages from a website, but my current Google Apps Script only pulls the first page of results. How do I use pagination in this app script? Total beginner here, thanks for your help!

```
   function myFunction() {
  var url = "xxxxxxxx"
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  
  var data = response.getContentText()
  
  var result = JSON.parse(data)
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  
  sheet.clear()
  
  var headerRow = ['Title','Brand','UPC','In Stock','Stock Level','Price','Seller','Next Day','Ship to Home', 'Link']
  
  sheet.appendRow(headerRow)
  
  for(var i=0; i<result.category_results.length; i++){
    
    var row = [result.category_results[i].product.title, result.category_results[i].product.brand, result.category_results[i].product.upc,result.category_results[i].inventory.in_stock, 
               result.category_results[i].inventory.stock_level, result.category_results[i].offers.primary.price, result.category_results[i].offers.primary.seller_name, 
                 result.category_results[i].fulfillment.next_day_shipping_eligible, result.category_results[i].fulfillment.ship_to_home, result.category_results[i].product.link]
    
    sheet.appendRow(row)
  
  }

}
```

Comment: It might depend on the URL. Sometimes different "pages" can be obtained via different URLs. For example a first page has ULR like:  `www.abc.com`, but next page could be something like this: `www.abc.com/search.php?&page=2` etc

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Each "page" is it's own URL. You have to parse the HTML in the first page and find the links to the subsequent pages.

Comment: If the it is the case what @YuriKhristich is describing then you can use a DO WHILE loop to loop trough that.